# open/close options affected by question locking?

Tags: support

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/459218) let me notice something I am wondering about: after it has been locked, my option to vote for *reopening* has disappeared:

[image: reopen missing]

Is this really a feature of the question lock which makes sense in any way?

Comment: MDMarra called. He wants his MSPaint art back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question Locking is supposed to be a mod tool for saying "Everyone! Hands off!". Voting up/down/close/open/etc on such a question makes no sense if the 2nd-level demi-gods of the site hath forbid it.

Comment: Somehow, I always thought that locking has just been done to prevent comments. So I was mistaken and it is just some sort of a mod-hammer?

Comment: @syneticon-dj A lock is the tool of choice when things get out of hand (insane comments, edit wars, etc.) - in the hierarchy of hammers it's in between "closed" and "deleted".

Comment: @syneticon-dj I think you are thinking of "Protected" status.

Comment: @syneticon-dj There different flavors of locking. Some locks still allow you to vote, but not comment or answer. The Historical lock is the frozen-in-carbonite version.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 ah, this explains some of my confusion, thanks.